# JSX Implementing Stopwatch

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

working on implementing a stopwatch using JSX
This is my current component

```
<Stopwatch laps msecs start={stopwatchStart}
    reset={stopwatchReset}
    options={{
        text: {
            fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular',
            fontSize: 15,
            color: '#FFF',
        },
    }}
    msecs={false}
/>
```

However I get an error saying

JSX elements cannot have multiple attributes with the same name.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Remove the duplicate prop, as the error says? Figure out which value you want to pass, and then pass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have prop `msecs` repeated, remove one of them, the one that makes sense to you

```
<Stopwatch laps start={stopwatchStart}
    reset={stopwatchReset}
    options={{
        text: {
            fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular',
            fontSize: 15,
            color: '#FFF',
        },
    }}
    msecs={false}
/>
```